# Why is there a gap in between two divs and no overlap

Tags: html, css

I've come here before with great results and appreciate the help. I've been searching and searching through my code to figure out what is going on and I can't quite get it. At my site http://www.hirelogo.com underneath the navigation there is a random space insert. I've removed div ".top" as I thought maybe that was causing the issue, but this is not to my knowledge. I've been dissecting with firebug, but find no overlap issues that may cause this. The area of random space I'm referring to is below the navigation "home,design team..ect" and the "step1, step 2 graphic" . I hope someone give me a little nudge to whats going on here. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following div is causing a space of `8px`.

```
.top {
    clear: both;
    height: 8px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 920px;
}
```

The image to the left has `padding` and `line-height` added to it as well:

```
.descrSplash {
    clear: both;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 150%;
    padding-top: 40px;
    width: 436px;
}
```

Finally the right image has `10px` added above and below it. Also the image is large and can be cropped to raise it up unless you want to set a `negative margin`.